# Accessing items in multiple layouts

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I have a main ScrollView that contains a LinearLayout. Within this linear layout, I have 10 additional linear layouts stacked vertically and want to include buttons in them but I can't access the buttons by their view id in my activity. Is there a way I can set this up to make those buttons visible in my activity so I can add functionality?

Thanks!

- Josh

Comment: If you get a reference to the LinearLayout instances, then you should be able to do something like `layout.findViewById(R.id.button)` on them. It would be helpful if you added some of your XML layouts to your question, though

Comment: please add some code